# 301 редирект со всего раздела

Tags: redirect, .htaccess

Нужно, чтобы пользователей редиректило на главную страницу, если они зайдут на любую ссылку раздела. 
Например, site.ru/section/handbook/?id=1231 его перекидывает на главную.
И site.ru/section/ его тоже перекидывает на главную.

Надеюсь, объяснил понятно. Сам делаю так:

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule /section/(.*)$ / [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы мыслите правильно. В приведённом куске кода три ошибки: лишний слэш и лишние скобки (из-за слэша Ваш редирект работает не так, как Вы хотите, а скобки просто избыточны в данном случае), а также подразумеваемый, но пропущенный символ `^`, означающий начало строки в регулярном выражении.

Правильная запись будет такой:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^section/.*$ / [L,R=301]
```